SWR Mutation in my react app is getting an error 'Can’t trigger the mutation: missing key.'
I am trying to set up a POST and PUT use SWR mutation hook but I keep getting the error: Mutation error: Error: Can’t trigger the mutation: missing key.
Whatever I do, I cannot seem to solve the issue?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Code:
Handle request:
const { triggerMutation, data, error, isMutating } = useCustomSWRMutation();

  const handleVenueSubmit = async (data) => {
    const venue = {
      name: data.name,
      address: data.address,
      mapLink: data.mapLink,
      parkingInfo: data.parkingInfo,
      other: data.other,
      attachment: "",
      clubKey: auth.user.clubId,
      key: data.name?.replace(/ /g, ""),
      entityStatus: "Active",
    };

    try {
      const method = data.id ? "PUT" : "POST";
      const url = data.id
        ? `${API_URL}/api/venues/${data.id}`
        : `${API_URL}/api/venues`;

      const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
      };

      // Trigger the mutation with URL, data, method, and headers
      const result = await triggerMutation(url, {
        arg: venue,
        method,
        headers,
      });

      notification.success({
        message: data.id
          ? "Venue updated successfully"
          : "Venue added successfully",
        description: `${result.name} has been ${data.id ? "updated" : "added"} successfully`,
      });
      setOpen(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Mutation error:", error);
      notification.error({
        message: data.id ? "Error updating venue" : "Error adding venue",
        description: `There was an error ${data.id ? "updating" : "adding"} the venue`,
      });
    }
  };

SWRmutation hook:
import useSWRMutation from "swr/mutation";

const sendRequest = async (url, { arg, method, headers }) => {
  const options = {
    method: method || "POST", // Default to POST if method is not provided
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      ...headers,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(arg),
  };

  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  if (!response.ok) {
    const errorData = await response.json();
    throw new Error(errorData.message || "Something went wrong");
  }

  return await response.json();
};

const useCustomSWRMutation = () => {
  const { trigger, data, error, isMutating } = useSWRMutation(
    null,
    sendRequest
  );

  return { triggerMutation: trigger, data, error, isMutating };
};

export default useCustomSWRMutation;

Getting console error: Mutation error: Error: Can’t trigger the mutation: missing key.

The arguments of the useSWRMutation hook are the string key and the fetcher function.
You are calling this hook with the first argument null, which is not a valid key.
const { trigger, data, error, isMutating } = useSWRMutation(
    null,
    sendRequest
  );

Often the key is the API path, for example useSWRMutation('/api/user', sendRequest), but it can also be any arbitrary string.  In this example they use a constant useSWRSubscription('sub-key', subscribe);.
You can set the key to literally any string and your hook will work:
const useCustomSWRMutation = () => {
  const { trigger, data, error, isMutating } = useSWRMutation(
    'custom-mutation',
    sendRequest
  );

  return { triggerMutation: trigger, data, error, isMutating };
};

But you probably want to have different keys for the different places that you use this hook?  In that case, you can pass the key as an argument to the hook.
const useCustomSWRMutation = (key) => {
  const { trigger, data, error, isMutating } = useSWRMutation(
    key,
    sendRequest
  );

  return { triggerMutation: trigger, data, error, isMutating };
};

And then:
const { triggerMutation, data, error, isMutating } = useCustomSWRMutation('submit-venue');

